# Create a sum of two Array instances

Tags: c++, arrays, instance

The essence of what I want to do is to take two instances of Vector2D and create a third vector that is to be returned and made into the third instance. The problem I am facing is that I am not entirely sure on how to go ahead in doing so. I have tried to find the syntax for sending in instances, if there is such a one, but I have not managed to find anything useful in any of my books.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<array>
using namespace std;

class vector2D
{
    public:
        array<float, 2> get()
        {
            return xy_coord;
        }

        void set(float x, float y)
        {
            xy_coord[0] = x;
            xy_coord[1] = y;
        }

        array<float, 2> vectorAdd(a, b)
        {
            array<float, 2> c;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
            }

            return c;
        }

    private:
        array<float, 2> xy_coord;
};

int main()
{
    string y;
    vector2D a, b, c;
    array<float, 2> temp;
    a.set(2.0, 3.0);
    b.set(4.0, 5.0);
    temp = c.vectorAdd(a, b);
    c.set(temp[0], temp[1]);

    getline(cin, y);
}
```

The idea is to send in the instances a and b to vectorAdd and sum them up and then set c equal to the returned value (I am sure there is a better way to write the code in the main(), but I am not sure how). In short, what would a and b need to be defined as to make this work, assuming it can work at all.

Comment: You can allow C++ classes to work with operators. For example, you could have "a+b" have meaning.

Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading#Examples

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this instead, so you don't have to pass array around:

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector2D
{
private:

    double _x;
    double _y;

public:

    Vector2D() = delete;
    Vector2D(double x, double y) : _x(x), _y(y) {}
    double X() const { return _x; }
    double Y() const { return _y; }
    Vector2D operator+(Vector2D const &v) const
    {
        return Vector2D(X() + v.X(), Y() + v.Y());
    }

};

int main()
{  
    Vector2D v1(10.0, 20.0);
    Vector2D v2(100.0, 200.0);
    Vector2D v3 = v1 + v2;

    std::cout << v3.X() << " " << v3.Y();

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
110 220
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Do you need to use array<float, 2>?  Have you thought of using pair<float, float>?

A lot (all?) of the operations that you have in your Vector2D class come for free with Pair<>.
```

Then you just create operator+ as others have suggested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

using Coord = pair<float, float>;

template <typename L, typename R>
Coord operator+(const L& x, const R& y) { return std::make_pair(x.first + y.first, x.second + y.second); }

int main()
{

    Coord a { 5.0f, 6.0f };
    Coord b { 7.0f, 9.0f };
    Coord c = a + b;

    std::cout.precision(5);
    std::cout << "c= (" << std::fixed << c.first << ", " << c.second << ")" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```